# How do I loop a variable in the Javascript function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, variables

I have the following loop for a series of similar click events in jQuery. Everything works fine except for the last line below with the comment. How can I make each loop iteration call these functions respectively: step1(), step2(), step3(), etc.?

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    $("#stepbox" + i).click(function(){
    $("#step" + i).show();                     
    $("#stepswrapper section").not("#step" + i).hide();
    $("#stepbox" + i).addClass("stepboxactive");
    $("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox" + i).removeClass("stepboxactive");
    step + i(); // I'm stuck here. This doesn't work to create the function calls step1(), step2(), etc.
    });

}
```

Comment: Are step1 step2 step3 functions global? If so you can do `window['step' + i]()`

Comment: At the very least, put the functions into an array. But why do you need to dynamically call a function like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: setTimeout("step1()",0);

Comment: @Legends passing a string to setTimeout is exacly the same as calling eval().

Comment: @Aleuck And this means what?

Comment: @Legends this means you are calling the javascript compiler, which is very slow.

Comment: @Aleuck And what is quicker?

Comment: @Legends making an array of functions: `funcArray[0]()` , `funcArray[1]()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74670/discussion-between-legends-and-aleuck).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your functions are defined in the global context:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    $("#stepbox" + i).click(function(){
        $("#step" + i).show();                     
        $("#stepswrapper section").not("#step" + i).hide();
        $("#stepbox" + i).addClass("stepboxactive");
        $("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox" + i).removeClass("stepboxactive");
        window["step" + i]();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure, this might work. But needing to do so at all is a major code smell.

Comment: Uuuu I can smell it from here :D

Answer (score 1):

make an array of the step functions.

```
var step = [
  function () { /* step 0 */ },
  function () { /* step 1 */ },
  function () { /* step 2 */ }
  // ...
];
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $("#stepbox" + i).click(function(){
        $("#step" + i).show();                     
        $("#stepswrapper section").not("#step" + i).hide();
        $("#stepbox" + i).addClass("stepboxactive");
        $("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox" + i).removeClass("stepboxactive");
        step[i]();
    });
}
```

Comment: @dave

I tried both approaches but they didn't work.

Here's how my code is structured:

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#stepbox1").click(function(){
$("#step1").show();        
$("#stepswrapper section").not("#step1").hide();
$("#stepbox1").addClass("stepboxactive");
$("#stepboxmain div").not("#stepbox1").removeClass("stepboxactive");
step1();
});

// ...Plus another three of these click functions. And then:

function step1() {
// Stuff here
}

// ...Plus another three of these functions called from the buttons

});